# Jquery $(...).modal is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm keep getting the Jquery $(...).modal is not a function error.

I know this error happens if jquery isn't loaded. My thing is i'm very sure it's loaded in correctly.

In my _Layout i load a partial named "_LayoutDefaultHead".

```
<head>
    @Html.Partial("_LayoutDefaultHead")
    @Html.Partial("_Head")
</head>
```

In that partial i'm loading jquery.

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/jquery.adnsfalias.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/lazysize.min.js" async></script>
```

On the bottom of the _Layout i'm loading another partial named "_LayoutDefaultBodyClose";

```
@Html.Partial("_LayoutDefaultBodyClose")
```

In this partial i'm calling a function which uses $(...).Modal.

```
@Html.Raw(ACMT_Helpers.GetPopup())

    ($('#popup-" + ID + "-modal').modal('show');sessionStorage['popup-" + ID + "-modal'] = 'true';)
```

Even tho i loaded Jquery way earlier it isn't loaded in the "_LayoutDefaultBodyClose" and i can't see why.

Does someone know what i'm doing wrong?

Here's the sourcecode so you can see it's almost impossible that it doesn't work:

On line 1980 bootstrap gets included. On line 1990 is a document ready and on 1991 it's throwing the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbQfM.png)

The function .modal() even gets used earlier on line 1838.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VD9j.png)

Jquery is already loaded on line 54.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/okBus.png)

Comment: I think you need to include bootstrap, since I believe .modal is in boostrap. Try look here http://net-informations.com/jq/iq/modal.htm

Comment: bootstrap is also included before that function.

Comment: Boostrap js needs to be include after jquery

Comment: yes it is included before that function and after jquery.

Comment: Also should `$('#popup-" + ID + "-modal')` not be `$('#popup-' + ID + '-modal')`

Comment: Nope it's jquery code that gets appended via StringAppender in C# . 
sbScripts.AppendLine("if (sessionStorage['popup-" + ID + "-modal']")
 The ID comes from the C# code.

Comment: May I ask why you use StringAppender to add jquery code in your html page?

Comment: I just changed my place of work so that's new for me to but i think it's because of two reasons. Data that can only be accessed via this helper and because there would be to many code in the layoutdefault because of the huge size of the project.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I included the sourceCode so you can see everything Carsten said is already done.

Comment: That can happen if jquery is *reloaded* after bootstrap.js has been loaded.  So your earlier code works, then jquery reloads and your later code doesn't work.   Easiest way to check is to add a temporary console.log or alert to the top of the jquery.js.

Comment: @freedomn-m thanks for the answer. It sadly wasn't the case and jquery only gets loaded once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the new bootstrap version cause it changed to vanillajs instead of jquery like the older versions. It says that you can still use it with jquery but it only works in the console after the page is loaded and not yet with .ready. I fixxed the issue just with using an older version of bootstrap.js. I know not the best solution but i can't waste more time with that problem.

Comment: In that case, if `$(".modal").modal("show")` is not working but does work with DOM elements, you may be able to use `$(".modal")[0].modal("show")` - ie add `[0]` after the `$(selector)`- or whatever the method is for the version you're using (which has not been specified)

Comment: I'll try that thanks :)